# ¿Por qué no se puede ver toda la información de un DataFrame con muchos datos en Python?

Tags: python

Estoy en el estudio de los códigos para la programación en Python, y me he encontrado con una duda, es que especialmente cuando quieres imprimir en la pantalla la información de un DataFrame con muchos datos, Python solo expone, una parte. ¿Porque? ¿Existe alguna forma de que Python te muestre toda la información? 
Es para mi trabajo de investigación. Agradeceré mucho sus respuestas.

Comment: Utiliza alguna IDE como PyCharm, con el debugger puedes inspeccionar le contenido de Dataframes y numpy array como matrices visualmente en el editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrias cambiar la configuración de cuantas filas debe mostrar:

```
  pd.set_option('display.max_rows', df.shape[0]+1)
  print(df)
```

EDICIÓN: Se supone que el datafraame df ya contiene datos en este ejemplo

Comment: me sale IndexError: tuple index out of range

Comment: Quitarle el más 1 del shape

Comment: Puedes también poner el codigo

Answer (score 1):

como estás?

Estás utilizando pandas?
Si es así, puedes utilizar herramientas como 
https://github.com/pandas-profiling/pandas-profiling 
para realizar profiling de los datos que queires ver.
El ver "todos" los muchas veces no es posible, mas si trabajas con bigdata, por lo que hay que realizar tareas de profiling para estudiar los mismos.

Si no usas pandas, te recomiendo que lo hagas ya que es la herramienta nùmero 1 de Python para análitica.

Espero te sirva!!

Comment: Hola, si estoy utilizando Pandas